# How to get maximum value in multi dimension array in js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here I want to get maximum value of this multi dimensional  array where tax_value is greater .

```html
0:{id: "61", tax_value: "2.00000000"}
1:{id: "81", tax_value: "12.00000000"}
```

Here I am getting the array using this code.

```js
 var array = new Array();
        if (typeof $('select[id^=item_tax]') !== "undefined")
        {
            $('select[id^=item_tax]').each(function (i, e)
            {
                if ($(e).val() > 0)
                {
                    array.push({id: $(e).val(), tax_value: $(e).find('option:selected').data('value')});
                }
            });


        }
        console.log(array);//multi dimensional array is coming as output
```

How to get maximum value from this array.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For returning the max `tax_value`**, use `map`

```
var maxTaxValue = Math.max.apply( null, array.map( s => s.tax_value ) );
```

**For returning the entire object** with max `tax_value`.

```
var obj = array.find( s => s.tax_value == maxTaxValue )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new ES6 functions to get the max tax value but you can also get the max while doing the loop.

*No need for additional loop or function.*

```
var array = new Array();
var maxValue = 0; //Init the max variable
if (typeof $('select[id^=item_tax]') !== "undefined")
{
    $('select[id^=item_tax]').each(function (i, e)
    {
        if ($(e).val() > 0)
        {
                array.push({id: $(e).val(), tax_value: $(e).find('option:selected').data('value')});
        }

        //Test weather the current tax is greater. Assign the value
        var taxValue = Number( $(e).find('option:selected').data('value') );
        if ( maxValue < taxValue ) maxValue = taxValue;
    });
}

console.log( maxValue );
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you try in this way. You can get an array which has each row's maximum.
after that you can get the overal maximum from it